# What is the fastest way to convert from a unixtime to a numpy.datetime64?

Tags: python, numpy, unix-timestamp

I suppose that the key here is to have the less number of intermediate conversions but I'm not able to find a simple way in the new Numpy 2.0 dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `numpy.datetime64` objects are basically unix times internally (with 6 extra significant digits to account for millisecond precision).  You just need to multiply by `1e6`.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate a few unix time stamps near today...
x = np.arange(1326706251, 1326706260)

# Convert to datetimes...
x *= 1e6
x = x.view(np.datetime64)

print x
```

This yields:

```
[2012-01-16 09:30:51 2012-01-16 09:30:52 2012-01-16 09:30:53
 2012-01-16 09:30:54 2012-01-16 09:30:55 2012-01-16 09:30:56
 2012-01-16 09:30:57 2012-01-16 09:30:58 2012-01-16 09:30:59]
```

Comment: Multiplying by 1e6 seems that overflows the np.datetime64. On the other hand using np.datetime64(1326706251,'s') seems that gives the results I want. Which version of numpy are you using?

Comment: I'm using `1.6`. It doesn't overflow it for me, and `np.datetime64` doesn't take a second argument for me, either...

Comment: Ok, so perhaps it's me using the 2.0 dev. Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, I'd heard there were a lot of changes coming to numpy's datetime behavior in 2.0... My answer above is very implementation-specific, and apparently it's going to be changing soon. Glad you found something else that worked!

Comment: not a very clean solution in my opinion, the solution by Achilles1515 is more on point. Also observe my comment below it.

Answer (score 2):

As of NumPy 1.18:

```py
import numpy as np

timestamp = np.datetime64(1326706251, 's')
print(timestamp)
```

Output:

```
2012-01-16T09:30:51
```

Comment: for an array of timestamps, `a`, you can do `a.astype('datetime64[s]')`